# How to store checkbox 'checked' status in a session?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I'm writing a website in which there is a gallery of photos. Under every photo there is a form with a single checkbox, so I can check it and it should stay checked during the session.

The problem is that nothing that I've written is working and every time I checked the checkbox and hit submit, it keeps unchecking. Here is my form:

```
<?= $i = 0; ?>
<?php if (count($photos)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($photos as $photo): ?>
        <?= $checkbox['_id'] = $photo['_id']; ?>
        <div class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="view?id=<?= $photo['_id'] ?>">
                <img src="images/<?= $photo['title'] . "_min." . $photo['extension'] ?>" alt="Toster">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Tytuł: <?= $photo['title'] ?> </div>
            <div class="desc">Autor: <?= $photo['author'] ?></div>
            <div class="desc"><a href="delete?id=<?= $photo['_id'] ?>">Delete</a></div>
            <div class="desc">
                <form action="remember_ses" method="post">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<?= $i ?>]" value="wybrane"><?= $photo['_id'] ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $checkbox['_id']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Remember" id="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $i = $i + 1; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Does your session was [started](http://php.net/session_start) ?

Comment: Side note: you don't want to do this: `name="checkbox[<?=$i ?>]"` that should just be `name="checkbox"` since you are only passing 1 per form submit.

Comment: Also, I dont see any code above that handles anything with trying to remember the form submit data. Nothing about _SESSION, nor _POST. ??

Comment: Yes, session has been started and I need to name the checkboxes that way because later i need to include the pictures that were checked on other site.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the photo id to the session variable, later each time you execute the loop, you check if the id of the photo matches the session id if you add 'checked' to the input